Smoothing property of the heat kernel on the one-dimensional torus
Let $G=G(x,t)$ be the heat kernel on the one-dimensional torus $\mathbb{T}^1,$ with $x \in \mathbb{T}^1$ and $t \in (0,T].$ $G$ is given by \begin{equation}
    G(x,t) = (4  \pi t)^{-1/2} \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \exp \left ( - \frac{(x+k)^2}{4t}   \right),
    \end{equation}
and is smooth, meaning $G \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{T}^1 \times (0,T])$ and is compactly supported w.r.t to $x,$ since it is defined on the torus.
Moreover, let $u \in L^\infty((0,T); L^1(\mathbb{T}^1))$ and $r \in L^\infty((0,T); L^\infty(\mathbb{T}^1)).$ We consider the following convolution:
$$ w(x,t) := \int_{0}^{t} \int_{\mathbb{T}^1}  G(x-y,t-s)r(y,s)u(y,s) \, dyds.$$
My question is, how much regularity can we expect for $w$? I would need $w \in C^{1/2}(\mathbb{T}^1 \times [0,T]).$
I suppose it is possible to expect smoothness w.r.t to $x,$ since $G$ is compactly supported on the torus but what about $t$?
I would be very grateful for help!

The answer is the same as on the real line. There's no hope for $C^1$ regularity (when, e.g, $r u$ is the indicator function of $\mathbb T^1 \times [T/2,T]$, then $w(x, t) = \max{0, t-T/2}$), and one indeed has $w \in C^{1/2}$ is $r u$ is bounded. Under your assumptions, if $r u$ is $L^\infty([0,T],L^1(\mathbb T^1))$, I suppose the answer is the same, but I did not try to work out the details (or find this in the literature). Note, however, that $w$ need not be smooth with respect to $x$.

Thanks for the answer. $w \in C^{1/2}$ would be enough for me. A literature reference would be helpful.
